# When do Core Data merge conflicts occur, exactly?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, ios4

Say I have an app with the following entities: Page <->> BookPosition <<-> Book. My app's job is to empower users to mix and match pages in one or more picture books using a GUI (on the main thread).

Now, two points:

1. When a user modifies a book, `BookPositions` are created and destroyed, but never changed.
2. A page can be shared across multiple books.

Let's say I synchronize a bevy of picture books (some already exist, some are new) on a background thread using a shared PSC, a separate MOC, and watertight thread isolation. Before I start the process, I make sure users can't modify any one to-be-synced book until after the MOC on the background thread has invoked `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` for that book, and correspondingly generated an `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, which is merged in on the main thread using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`:.

Me being naive, I didn't expect this approach would ever cause a merge conflict since - ostensibly - none of the entities in question ever have the potential to change on one thread before a call to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` can bring both MOCs up to date. However, merge conflicts *will* occur on the background thread if users make a change on the main thread that mutates the set of BookPositions associated with a Page shared between an already-synced book and a to-be-synced book.

The takeaway here is that changing (adding or removing) entities on the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship results in a new version of the object on the "one" side, even when nothing else on the "one" side has changed. Everything makes sense so far, and I figured I could resolve the problem by setting a merge policy (either `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` or `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` should work here?) on the background MOC. Unfortunately (and unexpectedly), after setting a merge policy, I wound up with conflicts on the main thread, which is precisely why I'm confused.

I'd like to know at what point the data in my persistent store is going out of sync with my MOC on the main thread. Does the discrepancy occur as the background MOC is saving / before it has a chance to post a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`?

I seem to be able to resolve the problem by also setting a merge policy on the main MOC, but if possible, I'd like to know exactly what's going on here.